# Golod Shafarevich Inequality and Inequalities among higher Cohomology groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, homological-algebra, finite-groups, group-cohomology

As a consequence of Golod- Shafarevich, we get an inequality between second cohomology group of a $p$-group with coefficients in $F_p$ and the first cohomology group of a $p$-group with coefficients in $F_p$. My question: Do we know any inequalities between $\operatorname{dim}H^{i+1}(G, F_p)$ and $\operatorname{dim}H^{i}(G, F_p)$ for a $p$-group $G$ for all $i$ or say at least for $i=2$?

Comment: What does inequality between abelian groups mean?

Comment: It should say an inequality involving the dimensions of those groups, regarded as $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector spaces.